# Webscraping: Value I need is "calculating"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm scraping the nba top shop website to identify my spot in the queue (You can easily wait hours before it's your turn). I want to make a tool that ill email you when it's your turn, so you don't spend all day on the computer. The issue is the value I scrape using request comes up as "calculating" even though comes up as a number of the web page.

Here's my code. The won't work by the time you are reading this as the queue is over.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

site = request.urlopen("https://queue.nbatopshot.com/?c=dapperlabs&e=f2yggcaz7t&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nbatopshot.com%2Fapi%2Fpurchase%2Fqueue-callback%3FlistingID%3D279f41e1-84b4-41bd-81b2-61334e64c86c&cv=34890450&cid=en-US").read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(site)


Line_number = soup.find(id="MainPart_lbUsersInLineAheadOfYou")

print(Line_number)
```

Here is what I see when I inspect the site:

```
<span id="MainPart_lbUsersInLineAheadOfYou" data-bind="visible: layout.usersInLineAheadOfYouVisible, text: ticket.usersInLineAheadOfYou">27581</span>
```

Here is what I see when I run the requests:

```
<span data-bind="visible: layout.usersInLineAheadOfYouVisible, text: ticket.usersInLineAheadOfYou" id="MainPart_lbUsersInLineAheadOfYou" style="display: none;">calculating...</span>
```

Any advice on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"time=None"` at the end of your urlopen, like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

site = request.urlopen("https://queue.nbatopshot.com/?c=dapperlabs&e=f2yggcaz7t&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nbatopshot.com%2Fapi%2Fpurchase%2Fqueue-callback%3FlistingID%3D279f41e1-84b4-41bd-81b2-61334e64c86c&cv=34890450&cid=en-US", timeout=None).read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(site)


Line_number = soup.find(id="MainPart_lbUsersInLineAheadOfYou")

print(Line_number)
```

You can read more [here](http://%20https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) about timeouts.

If that doesn't work you may need to resort to using Selenium.